# Clock and Worker Dynos in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a dyno called "clock" and one called "web".

I am reading this article:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes

Right now my clock process executes SQL commands to update a database.  Why would I want the clock to pass them off to a separate dyno, and not execute them itself? I only update every two hours, so the extra worker dyno would be idle most of the time.  What behavior could I expect if I don't create a separate dyno? (I have been experiencing some lag). A downside with creating a third dyno is I might pay a little more a month and I would have to do some refactoring.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I did not. @Notflip